# Table td/ Ul li stack over eachother

Tags: html, css, sass

I have been practicing css for some time and today a problem occured that i'm not able to figure out.

I'm "drawing" a Space Invaders picture and when i try to add the invaders (alien1, alien2, alien3 etc.) then they stack over eachother. I have tried to add them as a list and also as a table... None of them works. I also tried the `display: inline/inline-block` but that made them dissapear.

What could be my problem here?

Here's the link: http://codepen.io/kaur16/pen/ONKOMo

Comment: Please provide your code example here on SO instead of codepen. The pen can disappear or get modified, so future readers can't profit from you question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your aliens have a `display` type of `inline-block` and a `margin-right` of at least the alien sprite's width:

```
.alien1 {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  margin-right: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 
    20px 5px 0 #FFF,
    ...,
    60px 40px 0 #FFF;
}
```

Updated codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNwdpW

*Additionally, you may want to consider creating a master alien class that contains common alien settings:*

```
.alien {
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    margin-right: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Then list your specific aliens:

```
.alien1 {
  box-shadow: 
    20px 5px 0 #FFF,
    ...,
    60px 40px 0 #FFF;
}

.alien2 {
  box-shadow: 
    15px 5px 0 #FFF,
    ...,
    55px 40px 0 #FFF;
}

...
```

So then your alien `td` element would look like: `<td class="alien alien1"></td>`

Answer (score 0):

add a class like below to css .
Add that class to each alien class like `<td class="alien1 add"></td>`

```
.add{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px 50px;
}
```

What i did is add a `display:inline-block` and added a `margin` of `50px` to both the sides of each alien.